# Why is OFFSET / FETCH causing Performance issues with Queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, sql-server-2019

My SQL query is taking too much time to complete execution while using `OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY`

It will complete execution in 0 seconds if I

1. Remove the `FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` and use only `OFFSET 20 ROWS`
2. Insert the data into a temp table first and then use `OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY`

I want to know why this happening

I have this select query in T-SQL

```
SELECT ITEM.ID ITEM_ID, ITEM.CODE ITEM_CODE, ITEM.DESCRIPTION ITEM_NAME
    , ITEM.CODE_CATEGORY_ID CATEGORY_ID, ITEM_CAT.CODE CATEGORY_CODE
    , ITEM_CAT.NAME CATEGORY_NAME
FROM B1.SP_ITEM_MF ITEM
INNER JOIN B1.SP_ADMIN_STRUCTURE ITEM_CAT ON ITEM.CODE_CATEGORY_ID = ITEM_CAT.ID
    AND ITEM_CAT.RECORD_TYPE ='CD'
    AND ITEM_CAT.ACTIVE='Y'
INNER JOIN [A1].SP_REQ_CATEGORY_MAPPING MAP ON MAP.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID = ITEM.CODE_CATEGORY_ID
INNER JOIN B1.SP_ADMIN_STRUCTURE  REQ_CAT ON REQ_CAT.ID = MAP.REQ_CATEGORY_ID
    AND REQ_CAT.RECORD_TYPE = 'RQ'
    AND REQ_CAT.ACTIVE = 'Y'
    AND REQ_CAT.CODE IN ('CRW','SCHF')
ORDER BY ITEM.CODE
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Which is returning 20 records and taking more than 5 minutes to complete execution.

When I remove the `FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` it returns 2000 records and complete execution in just 0 seconds.

Also if I rewrite the query to insert the result set into a temp table (added below) and then use `OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` on that result set that also complete execution in 0 seconds .

```
CREATE TABLE #TempPagination (
    RowNum INT,
    ITEM_ID BIGINT,
    ITEM_CODE VARCHAR(64),
    ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(256),
    CATEGORY_ID INT,
    CATEGORY_CODE VARCHAR(8),
    CATEGORY_NAME VARCHAR(64)
);

INSERT INTO #TempPagination (ITEM_ID, ITEM_CODE, ITEM_NAME, CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_CODE, CATEGORY_NAME)
SELECT ITEM.ID ITEM_ID, ITEM.CODE ITEM_CODE, ITEM.DESCRIPTION ITEM_NAME
    , ITEM.CODE_CATEGORY_ID CATEGORY_ID,ITEM_CAT.CODE CATEGORY_CODE,ITEM_CAT.NAME CATEGORY_NAME
FROM B1.SP_ITEM_MF ITEM
INNER JOIN B1.SP_ADMIN_STRUCTURE ITEM_CAT ON ITEM.CODE_CATEGORY_ID = ITEM_CAT.ID
    AND ITEM_CAT.RECORD_TYPE = 'CD'
    AND ITEM_CAT.ACTIVE = 'Y'
INNER JOIN A1.SP_REQ_CATEGORY_MAPPING MAP ON MAP.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID = ITEM.CODE_CATEGORY_ID
INNER JOIN B1.SP_ADMIN_STRUCTURE REQ_CAT ON REQ_CAT.ID = MAP.REQ_CATEGORY_ID
    AND REQ_CAT.RECORD_TYPE = 'RQ'
    AND REQ_CAT.ACTIVE = 'Y'
    AND REQ_CAT.CODE IN ('CRW','SCHF');

SELECT 
    ITEM_ID,
    ITEM_CODE,
    ITEM_NAME,
    CATEGORY_ID,
    CATEGORY_CODE,
    CATEGORY_NAME
FROM #TempPagination
ORDER BY ITEM_CODE
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;

DROP TABLE #TempPagination;
```

Can someone explain why this happening? I have indexes on the columns and the version I am using is 2019.

1. Why is the query taking more time without the temp table, and not taking time when inserted into temp table first?
2. Why is `FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` causing too much performance degradation?

Plan with temp table: https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1_VmgyAa

Plan without temp table: https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByLhQeJAp

Comment: brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1_VmgyAa       ,                     
brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByLhQeJAp here is the plans for both queries, i changed the 20 rows to 1 rows

Comment: You haven't actually given us the plan with OFFSET - you gave plan with temp table.